# Spring Boot does not register HttpMessageConverter during test run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest-assured, spring-boot-test

I'm running a Spring Boot app and I've registered a new `HttpMessageConverter` called `CsvCompactVenueHttpMessageConverter`, here's the code for it:

```
@Component
public class CsvCompactVenueHttpMessageConverter extends
    AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Collection<CompactVenue>> {

    public CsvCompactVenueHttpMessageConverter() {
       super(MediaType.valueOf(TEXT_CSV));
    }

   >> message converter implementation code <<
}
```

It extends `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` and is registered as a bean on class `WebConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CsvCompactVenueHttpMessageConverter csvCompactVenueHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new CsvCompactVenueHttpMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

Then I have a rest resource called `FoursquareResource`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foursquare")
public class FoursquareResource {

    @Autowired
    FoursquareService foursquareService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{location}", produces = {"application/json", "text/csv"})
    public Collection<CompactVenue> searchVenuesByLocationAndIncreasingRange(@PathVariable String location, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer numQueries) throws FoursquareApiException, FoursquareServiceException {
        return foursquareService.searchVenuesByLocationAndIncreasingRange(location, numQueries);
    }
}
```

When I run the app and call `http://localhost:8080/foursquare/New York NY` it works fine and renders the `text/csv` response.

But when running the test with RestAssured and `@SpringBootTest` I get a HTTP 406 response (because I think it did not register correctly the `HttpMessageConverter` for `text/csv`), here's the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class FoursquareResourceTest {

    @Mock
    FoursquareService foursquareService;

    @InjectMocks
    FoursquareResource foursquareResource;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        CompactVenue venue = new CompactVenue();
        FieldUtils.writeField(venue, "id", "aUfmEW745", true);
        Collection<CompactVenue> venues = new ArrayList<>();
        venues.add(venue);
        when(foursquareService.searchVenuesByLocationAndIncreasingRange(any(), any())).thenReturn(venues);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearchVenuesByLocationAndIncreasingRangeCsv() throws Exception {
        MockMvcResponse response =
        given().
            accept("text/csv").
            standaloneSetup(foursquareResource).
        when().
            get(String.format("/foursquare/%s?numQueries=%d",location,numQueries)).
        then().
            statusCode(200).
        extract().response();

        log.info(response.body().print());
    }
```

}

I'm not sure why do I get a right answer when running the Spring Boot app but the 406 error when running as a Test. It looks like the new `HttpMessageConverter` is not registered on the tests but I can't see why.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Is the package of WebConfiguration at least at the same level or nested below the FoursquareResourceTest? If not, that could the problem. I'm assuming you have a SpringBootApplication annotation somewhere, otherwise, this won't work either.

Comment: Yes, I have a `@SpringBootApplication` on the root path. The `@ComponentScan` should be working fine because it worked when running the app.

Answer (score 2):

`406 Not Acceptable` just means that the controller is not able to serve the representation, requested by the client. In your case the client indicates its capability to read `text/csv` by sending `Accept` header, but the controller is not able to send `text/csv` back. Most probably lacking your converter. To understand why, it is important to understand one thing about `MockMvc`.
It is not clear, how your `MockMvc` is initialized, but I assume it is standalone setup. Be aware that `standaloneSetup` creates a **new** application context, where the beans from you standard configurations are not registered, including your custom converter. This explains, why the code works in a "normal" run, but fails in test. To overcome this, either use `webAppContextSetup` (which will start the application and embedded Jetty/Tomcat) with injected application context or manually set the converters by calling `setMessageConverters` on `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder`. For example,

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(controller)
        .setMessageConverters(new SomeConverter(),
                new SomeOtherConverter())
        .build();
```

You can then reuse the `mockMvc` object in your  REST Assure just by calling

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved it by injecting the `HttpMessageConverters` and manually adding them to the `MockMvc` object:

```
@Autowired
private HttpMessageConverter[] httpMessageConverters;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It will import your `WebConfiguration` class.

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = FoursquareResource.class)
@Import(FoursquareService.class)
public class FoursquareResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FoursquareService foursquareService;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        CompactVenue venue = new CompactVenue();
        FieldUtils.writeField(venue, "id", "aUfmEW745", true);
        Collection<CompactVenue> venues = Collections.singletonList(venue);
        when(foursquareService.searchVenuesByLocationAndIncreasingRange(any(), any())).thenReturn(venues);

        String location = "location";
        int numQueries = 4;
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/foursquare/{location}?numQueries={numQueries}", location, numQueries).contentType("text/csv"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn().getResponse();

        log.info(response.getContentAsString());
    }

}
```